# Finding maximum along nth dimension in C

Tags: c, optimization

I'm working on a problem where the execution time is critical. I have another C function that produces 3-D grids of values at a series of timestamps. What I want is to find the `max_value` in each 3-D grid at each timestamp. Additionally I am tracking the average value (`sum / ncell`) of each grid, and returning a maximum normalised by the average value.

I am not proficient in C, so I wanted to check if there is anything I am missing, either in terms of actual code, or use of OpenMP. I guess my question is:

What is the most efficient way to find the maximum values of a n-dimensional array sliced along the nth dimension?

I understand that the best you can hope for (as the grids are unordered) is O(n). My assessment is that this problem is then O(m x n), m = time dimension, n = dimension of the grid, and I think my implementation reaches that. Typically values for these dimensions are perhaps m=5000 to 20000, n=200*200*60.

Currently, I am timing my Python wrapper function (which includes the initialisation of the `numpy.ndarray`s that receive the max, normMax, and maxIndex values:

- m = 2400
- n = 54000
- threads = 8

For which I am averaging ~0.33 seconds to find the maximum values.

If it's relevant, this is on my laptop with:

- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz (6MB cache)
- 32GB RAM

Code:

```
void find_max(double *mapPt, double *maxPt, double *normMaxPt,
              int64_t *indexPt, int32_t nsamp, int32_t ncell,
              int64_t threads)
{
    double  maxValue, currentValue, sum;
    int32_t cell, maxIndex, timeSample;

    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(threads)
    for (timeSample=0; timeSample<nsamp; timeSample++)
    {
        maxValue = 0.0;
        maxIndex = 0;
        sum = 0.0;
        for (cell=0; cell<ncell; cell++)
        {
            currentValue = mapPt[cell * nsamp + timeSample];
            sum += currentValue;
            if (currentValue > maxValue)
            {
                maxValue = currentValue;
                maxIndex = cell;
            }
        }
        maxPt[timeSample] = maxValue;
        normMaxPt[timeSample] = maxValue * ncell / sum;
        indexPt[timeSample] = maxIndex;
    }
}
```

I am compiling with gcc 7.4.0, with the important flags probably -Ofast and -lm.

I am completely happy for the answer to be "there's nothing more you can do", just want to know for peace of mind.

Comment: This will fail if the first value in a grid is < 0, and the remaining values are <= 0.  In that case, it will falsely think the first value in the grid is 0 and that it's the maximum.  Can this happen?

Comment: Nope, the values are strictly positive. Everything works as expected at the moment.

Comment: Still, it would be cleaner to change `maxValue = 0.0;` to `maxValue = mapPt[timeSample];`, then change the loop to start at `cell=1`.  That would always work (assuming of course that `ncell >= 1`, which is necessary in any case).

Answer (score 1):

One suggestion I could see would be to have `double *timesame_mapcells = &mapPt[timeSample];` at the start of every thread.

Then you can just index with `cell * nsamp`, so one addition less per access. But the compiler might have been clever enough to optimize that.

You could also try having two incremented variables in the for loop:

```
for (cell = 0, map_idx = timeSample; cell < ncell; cell++, map_idx += nsamps)
{
    currentValue = mapPt[map_idx];
    [...]
}
```

Which might save some cycles with the timeSample addition every time + the nsamps multiplication.
Then again, this is just a suggestion for you to try. I don't know whether that will have an observable impact on performance. (But I'm curious to know whether that's the case if you give it a go)

Comment: If optimization is enabled, the compiler should do induction variable simplification which would eliminate the multiplies.  You could compare the generated code to see.

Comment: I tried both:

The former did appear to give an average speed increase, but only a couple of % (I tried 10 benchmark runs before/after change) so I'm a bit dubious. It's more likely my computer had freed itself of some other process, otherwise that's an expensive addition....

The latter appeared to have no effect. 

I'm not proficient enough with C to know how one might compare the generated code.

Thank you both.